# Copy emails defined by date

Tags: vba, outlook, archiving

I have two email accounts.
My Primary Email account is limited to a capacity of `4GB`, and my secondary account is limited to a capacity of `100GB`.

We are actively discouraged from using PST archive files, due to the ease of corruption taking place, when sitting on a server.

I often get emails with large excel files attached, which can be `10`-`15Mb`.

I access these email accounts via Outlook.

I have set up the file structure of my main account (the one limited to `4GB`) into my secondary account (which gets minimal direct traffic).

1. How do I select all emails to copy across to my secondary email account, from my primary account, based on the date that it was received ... e.g. say before `1st April 2018`?
2. How do I move these emails across from my Primary account to my secondary account, without manually copying & pasting?
3. Can this be done via `VBA`?

Please, I cannot switch which is my Primary Email or Secondary Email account.

Comment: Both your primary email account and your secondary account are files known as **Stores**.  Almost certainly their extensions are “PST” although they could be “OST”.  Whatever maximum size is set, if you save all your emails, they will eventually become full.  You can create another store with a name like “Archive” or “2017” and move emails to it which will reduce the size of the primary and secondary stores.  This new store will also have an extension of PST.  *Continued in next comment.*

Comment: *Continued from previous comment.* I do not understand why this PST file is any more likely to become corrupted than the first two.  Please explain why you are worried about corruption in case I have misunderstood your question.

Comment: It is not difficult to write VBA that will read through all the folders in a store identifying emails according to a property such as ReceivedTime and move those emails to the equivalent folder in another store.  Is that what you seek?

Comment: Hi Tony,es I want to identify according to date and move to another store

Answer (score 0):

**Health warnings**

I have moved emails from store to store many times over the years and have never experienced any corruption.  But that does not mean it cannot happen.  I recommend you take copies of the two stores before you try my macro.

On one occasion during testing, the macro stopped at the `Move` statement and reported an unknown error .  I restarted the macro.  It successfully moved the mail item that had given the error and continued to move the remaining mail items.  I have experienced transient errors like this with VBA macros before.  You may not experience an error like this.  If you do experience an error then try (1) restarting the macro by clicking <kbd>F5</kbd>, (2) stopping the macro and rerunning it and (3) moving the troublesome mail item with drag and drop.

**Assumption**

I assume you know how to access and use the Outlook VB Editor.  I can provide instructions if necessary.

**General routines**

I have been writing VBA macros for more than 15 years.  You will not be surprised that I have created subroutines and functions that I been able to use again.  I store these subroutines and functions in modules named "ModOutlook" and "ModExcel" if they are useful with a single Office package and "ModVBA" if they are useful with any Office package.

Please create a new module.  Clicking <kbd>F4</kbd> will open the Properties Window.  Modules only have one property: Name.  Please rename the new module “ModOutlook”.  This is not a requirement but I find giving my modules meaningful names very helpful.

Copy the code below to the new module:

```
Public Sub GetChildEmailFolderList(ByRef FldrPrnt As Folder, _
                                   ByRef FldrsChild As Collection)

  ' * On Exit, FldrsChild will contain a list of references to
  '   all the email folders within FldrPrnt

  ' * FldrPrnt references a store or a folder within a store.
  ' * On entry, FldrsChild is initialised to an empty collection.
  ' * GetChildEmailFolderListSub is called to add the details of every descendant,
  '   email folder of FldrPrnt to FldrsChild

  ' * An email folder is a folder with property DefaultItemType = OlMailItem

  ' 28Jul18  Created by adapting code from earlier routines

  Set FldrsChild = Nothing
  Set FldrsChild = New Collection

  Call GetChildEmailFolderListSub(FldrPrnt, FldrsChild)

End Sub
Sub GetChildEmailFolderListSub(ByRef FldrPrnt As Folder, _
                               ByRef FldrsChild As Collection)

  ' GetChildEmailFolderList initialises FldrsChild and then calls this
  ' routine to fill FldrsChild.

  ' This routine is recursive.  It is called with FldrPrnt referencing
  ' the root of the folder hierarchy of interest. It records the children
  ' that root folder in FldrsChild and calls itself for each of those
  ' children to find their children. It will call itself as many times
  ' as necessary to reach the bottom of the hierarchy.

  Dim FldrCrnt As Folder
  Dim InxFldrChild As Long

  For InxFldrChild = 1 To FldrPrnt.Folders.Count
    Set FldrCrnt = FldrPrnt.Folders(InxFldrChild)
    If FldrCrnt.DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then
      FldrsChild.Add FldrCrnt
      Call GetChildEmailFolderListSub(FldrCrnt, FldrsChild)
    End If
  Next

End Sub
Public Function GetCreateFldr(ByRef Store As Folder, _
                              ByRef FldrNameFull() As String) As Folder

  ' * Store identifies the store, which must exist, in which the folder is
  '   wanted.
  ' * FldrNameFull identifies a folder which is or is wanted within Store.
  '   Find the folder if it exists otherwise create it. Either way, return
  '   a reference to it.

  ' * If LB is the lower bound of FldrNameFull:
  '     * FldrNameFull(LB) is the name of a folder that is wanted within Store.
  '     * FldrNameFull(LB+1) is the name of a folder that is wanted within
  '       FldrNameFull(LB).
  '     * FldrNameFull(LB+2) is the name of a folder that is wanted within
  '       FldrNameFull(LB+1).
  '     * And so on until the full name of the wanted folder is specified.

  ' 17Oct16  Date coded not recorded but must be before this date

  Dim FldrChld As Folder
  Dim FldrCrnt As Folder
  Dim ChildExists As Boolean
  Dim InxC As Long
  Dim InxFN As Long

  Set FldrCrnt = Store

  For InxFN = LBound(FldrNameFull) To UBound(FldrNameFull)
    ChildExists = True
    ' Is FldrNameFull(InxFN) a child of FldrCrnt?
    On Error Resume Next
    Set FldrChld = Nothing   ' Ensure value is Nothing if following statement fails
    Set FldrChld = FldrCrnt.Folders(FldrNameFull(InxFN))
    On Error GoTo 0
    If FldrChld Is Nothing Then
      ' Child does not exist
      ChildExists = False
      Exit For
    End If
    Set FldrCrnt = FldrChld
  Next

  If ChildExists Then
    ' Folder already exists
  Else
    ' Folder does not exist. Create it and any children
    Set FldrCrnt = FldrCrnt.Folders.Add(FldrNameFull(InxFN))
    For InxFN = InxFN + 1 To UBound(FldrNameFull)
      Set FldrCrnt = FldrCrnt.Folders.Add(FldrNameFull(InxFN))
    Next
  End If

  Set GetCreateFldr = FldrCrnt

End FunctionPublic Function GetFldrNameFull(ByRef Fldr As Folder) As String()

  ' * Fldr is a folder. It could be a store, the child of a store,
  '   the grandchild of a store or more deeply nested.
  ' * Return the name of that folder as a string array in the sequence:
  '    (0)=StoreName (1)=Level1FolderName (2)=Level2FolderName  ...

  ' 12Oct16  Coded
  ' 20Oct16  Renamed from GetFldrNameStr and amended to return a string array
  '          rather than a string
  ' 28Jul18  Converted FldrNamesRev from string array to collection

  Dim FldrCrnt As Folder
  Dim FldrNames() As String
  Dim FldrNamesRev As New Collection
  Dim FldrPrnt As Folder
  Dim InxFN As Long
  Dim InxFnR As Long

  Set FldrCrnt = Fldr
  FldrNamesRev.Add Fldr.Name
  ' Loop getting parents until FldrCrnt has no parent.
  ' Add names of Fldr and all its parents to FldrNamesRev as they are found
  Do While True
    On Error Resume Next     ' Stop reporting errors
    Set FldrPrnt = Nothing   ' Ensure value is Nothing if following statement fails
    Set FldrPrnt = FldrCrnt.Parent
    On Error GoTo 0          ' Restart reporting errors
    If FldrPrnt Is Nothing Then
      ' FldrCrnt has no parent
      Exit Do
    End If
    FldrNamesRev.Add FldrPrnt.Name
    Set FldrCrnt = FldrPrnt
  Loop

  ' Copy names to FldrNames in reverse sequence so they end up in the correct sequence
  ReDim FldrNames(0 To FldrNamesRev.Count - 1)
  InxFN = 0
  For InxFnR = FldrNamesRev.Count To 1 Step -1
    FldrNames(InxFN) = FldrNamesRev(InxFnR)
    InxFN = InxFN + 1
  Next

  GetFldrNameFull = FldrNames

End Function
```

I believe I have included all the general routines I have used.  If you get an error because a routine is missing, let me know and I will add the missing routine.

These routine require an understanding of the Outlook Object Model and recursion.  I suggest you study them sometime but not until you understand macro `MoveEmails`.

**CtrlMoveEmails**

The macro `MoveEmails` is called with three parameters.  The macro below initialises those parameters and calls `MoveEmails`.   "tony archive 2015" and "tony archive" are two stores on my system that I have used for testing.  You must replace my names with the names of your email accounts.  I have coded a date and time into this macro that is relevant for my test stores.  You must change the date to something relevant for your accounts.  You could amend the macro to ask the operator for a date but I thought this would be the easiest approach.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CtrlMoveEmails()

  ' Create parameters for MoveEmails and call it.

  Dim LatestTimeToMove As Date
  Dim StoreDest As Folder       ' Destination store
  Dim StoreSrc As Folder        ' Source store:

  With Application.Session
    Set StoreDest = .Folders("tony archive 2015")
    Set StoreSrc = .Folders("tony archive")
  End With

  LatestTimeToMove = DateSerial(2015, 7, 3) + TimeSerial(23, 59, 59)

  Call MoveEmails(StoreSrc, StoreDest, LatestTimeToMove)

End Sub
```

**MoveEmails**

This macro takes about a minute with my test stores.  How long it takes on your system depends on how many emails it has to examine and how many of those it has to move.  I would normally use a form to display progress but it is difficult to explain how to create a form.  If you know how to create a form I will amend my answer to report progress in a better way.  The current macro uses Debug.Print to report progress which is not very satisfactory but is simpler than using a form

```
Sub MoveEmails(ByRef StoreSrc As Folder, _
               ByRef StoreDest As Folder, _
               ByVal LatestTimeToMove As Date)

  ' Move every email in StoreSrc or one of its children, with a
  ' ReceivedTime before LatestTimeToMove, to the same folder in
  ' StoreDest.

  ' If an email is found in FolderA11 of FolderA1 of StoreSrc, this routine
  ' creates FolderA11 of FolderA1 of StoreDest, if it does not exist, and
  ' moves the email to this destination folder.

  ' Both ScrRoot and StoreDest must be stores since this routine does not
  ' contain the code to handle the source and destination folders not being
  ' stores.

  ' 28Jul18  Coded

  Dim FldrDestCrnt As Folder
  Dim FldrDestNameFull() As String
  Dim FldrSrcCrnt As Folder
  Dim FldrSrcNameFull() As String
  Dim FldrsSrcChild As Collection
  Dim InxFldrsSrc As Long
  Dim InxItemCrnt As Long
  Dim InxName As Long
  Dim MailItemCrnt As MailItem

  ' Validate Src and Dest are stores
  FldrSrcNameFull = GetFldrNameFull(StoreSrc)
  If UBound(FldrSrcNameFull) > LBound(FldrSrcNameFull) Then
    Call MsgBox("Folder StoreSrc is not a store. I have no code " & _
                "to handle this situation", vbOKOnly)
    Exit Sub
  End If

  FldrDestNameFull = GetFldrNameFull(StoreDest)
  If UBound(FldrDestNameFull) > LBound(FldrDestNameFull) Then
    Call MsgBox("Folder StoreDest is not a store. I have no code " & _
                "to handle this situation", vbOKOnly)
    Exit Sub
  End If

  Debug.Print "Get list of all email folders in source store"
  DoEvents

  ' Get list of all email folders in StoreSrc
  Call GetChildEmailFolderList(StoreSrc, FldrsSrcChild)

  ' Process each email folder in FldrsSrcChild
  For InxFldrsSrc = 1 To FldrsSrcChild.Count

      Debug.Print "Processing folder " & InxFldrsSrc & " of " & _
                  FldrsSrcChild.Count
      DoEvents

    Set FldrSrcCrnt = FldrsSrcChild(InxFldrsSrc)
    Set FldrDestCrnt = Nothing  ' Only set if there is email to move to it

    ' FldrSrcCrnt.Items is a collection with items numbered 1 up to N by
    ' their position. If Item 1 is moved, Item 2 becomes Item 1. Processing
    ' items from the end of the collection first, ensures that the position of
    ' items not yet examined does not change.
    For InxItemCrnt = FldrSrcCrnt.Items.Count To 1 Step -1

      Debug.Print "  Item " & InxItemCrnt
      DoEvents

      On Error Resume Next        ' Stop reporting errors
      Set MailItemCrnt = Nothing
      Set MailItemCrnt = FldrSrcCrnt.Items(InxItemCrnt)
      On Error GoTo 0             ' Restart reporting errors
      If MailItemCrnt Is Nothing Then
        ' Current item is not a mail item.  Ignore mail item.
      ElseIf MailItemCrnt.ReceivedTime > LatestTimeToMove Then
        ' Too recent to move.  Ignore mail item.
      Else
        ' Move this email
        If FldrDestCrnt Is Nothing Then
          ' This is first email for this folder. Create destination
          ' folder unless it already exists.

          FldrSrcNameFull = GetFldrNameFull(FldrSrcCrnt)
          ' FldrNameFull is an array containing the full name of the source
          ' folder:
          '   FldrNameFull(0) is name of store
          '   FldrNameFull(1) is name of folder within store
          '   FldrNameFull(2) is name of folder within FldrNameFull(1)
          '   and so on until full name is specified.

          ' GetCreateFldr() requires an array like FldrNameFull but without
          ' the name of the store so discard element containng store name
          ReDim FldrDestNameFull(1 To UBound(FldrSrcNameFull))
          For InxName = 1 To UBound(FldrSrcNameFull)
            FldrDestNameFull(InxName) = FldrSrcNameFull(InxName)
          Next

          ' Check existence of destination folder. Create folder if it does not exist
          Set FldrDestCrnt = GetCreateFldr(StoreDest, FldrDestNameFull)

        End If

        MailItemCrnt.Move FldrDestCrnt

      End If

    Next InxItemCrnt

  Next InxFldrsSrc

End Sub
```

**Finally**

Come back with questions if necessary.

Comment: Many thanks for the guidance. As there a policy in the workplace about not saving files to the Hard-Drives, and only saving to the Network Drive, I think the corruption issue is due interruptions on our internal Network. We do have alternative tools available, but they only save the archive messages for 6 months.